# Does PHP XMLReader::open require allow_url_fopen to be on?

Tags: php, xmlreader

Does PHP XMLReader::open require allow_url_fopen to be on? I found no official documents regarding this.
If it is, what is the workaround if I have allow_url_fopen disabled?

Comment: Use something like curl to fetch your document, then load it into XMLReader.

Comment: I'd imagine so. You could test it easily.